# Write a title on itextPdf table border

Tags: android, itextpdf, pdfptable

I'm using `iTextPdf` to create a table on an android application.

I need to have the title of the table on its upper border as shown on the image below.

[image: table with title on border]

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [CellTitle](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/1833/draft#1639-celltitle.java) example. It creates a PDF in which titles are added on the cell border: [cell_title.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_cell_title.pdf)

[image]

This is accomplished by using a [cell event](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/cell-event):

```
class Title implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected String title;

    public Title(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        Chunk c = new Chunk(title);
        c.setBackground(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 
            new Phrase(c), position.getLeft(5), position.getTop(5), 0);
    }
}
```

A cell event can be added to a `PdfPCell` using the `setCellEvent()` method:

```
public PdfPCell getCell(String content, String title) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(content));
    cell.setCellEvent(new Title(title));
    cell.setPadding(5);
    return cell;
}
```

Next time, please show what you've tried before asking a question. Also take a look at the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) because everything you needed to answer your question yourself was available on the iText web site.